# Python Replace Html Codes With Corresponding Data

Tags: python

In Python I am trying to replace the codes '&#8220' and '”' in the string using the replace txt file, I have read many tutorials but cannot come up with a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

replace.txt
“ "
” "

string = 'Biden Brags About Handing Out “Record” Number of Work Visas to Foreigners'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `html` library, it has a function to "convert" those character codes to utf-8.

```
import html

funny_str = "Test &#8220"

print(html.unescape(funny_str))
```

Comment: Many thanks Guilherme Richter, Perfect!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace method...

```
new_string = string.replace('“', '')
```

and

```
new_string = string.replace('&#8820', '')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).